# Querying s3 parquet files using duckdb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, duckdb

I am trying to query my parquet files stored in my s3 bucket. But when I try to query from my s3 path it adds 's3.amazonaws.com' at the end of my bucket. this is my code

```
import boto3
import duckdb
import os

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/my-role',
    RoleSessionName='role'
)
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

con = duckdb.connect()
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = credentials['AccessKeyId']
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
os.environ['AWS_SESSION_TOKEN'] = credentials['SessionToken']

result = con.execute(query, ('s3://my-bucket/file.parquet',)).fetchall()
print(result)
```

So I am assuming the identity of my AWS account so I don't have to deal with the credentials. But upon executing this code I receive this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\School\Academiejaar 3\Semester 2\stage\energy_sellers_dashboard\query.py", line 21, in <module>
    result = con.execute(query).fetchall()
duckdb.IOException: IO Error: Unable to connect to URL "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/file.parquet": 400 (Bad Request)
```

I mean I get why it returns the bad request because the `.s3-amazonaws.com` should not be concatenated with my bucket string. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you're chasing the wrong problem.  Sure, in an **s3://** URI, you don't want the ".s3.amazonaws.com".  But your SDK needs to translate that s3:// URI into an https:// URI, for which it needs a valid DNS name.  So it needs to insert the ".s3.amazonaws.com".